# Continuous bijective map on a compact hausdorff space which is neither open nor closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space and let $Y$ be a topological space. Let $f: X → Y$ be a 
bijective continuous mapping. Then give an example that $f$ need not be an open map or closed map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Y$ is Hausdorff then a continuous $f$ from a compact $X$ to $Y$ will be a closed map and so such a bijection would be both open and closed and a homeomorphism.

So for an example we need to look at non-Hausdorff $Y$, and as $f$ is a continuous bijection $Y =f[X]$ will be compact always.

So take as an example $X=[0,1]$ in the usual topology. A model example of a compact Hausdorff space. Let $Y$ be $[0,1]$ in the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology), which is compact. Being lazy, define $f(x)=x$ and note it is clearly a bijection and continuous as a closed set $F$ of $Y$ is either $Y$ (with inverse image $X$) or finite (so its inverse image is finite, and in $X$ all finite sets are closed). So $f^{-1}[F]$ is closed for all closed $F \subseteq Y$ so $f$ is continuous. But $f$ is not open or closed ($f[(\frac13,\frac23)]$ is not cofinite, so not open in $Y$, $f[[\frac13,\frac23]]$ is not finite or $Y$ so not closed in $Y$).

Or even more trivially, same $f$ but take $Y$ in the trivial/indiscrete topology $\{\emptyset,Y\}$. Any map into an indiscrete space is continuous. Again $f$ is neither open nor closed. But the first example is "sharper", closer to the Hausdorff condition that will eliminate all examples.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.